# ngx-formly autofill one of three fields if two are already defined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, autofill, ngx-formly

i built three fields with formly. Together they can have a max of 100%. 
What ist best way to autofill one of the fields, if two have a value. 
For Example: 
 
First field: **30** 
Second field: **20** 
Then the third field should automatically filled with: **50**

What ist the "best" solution for this?

I already found a almost working way but iam sure my solution is not the goto. I used the formly lifecycle hooks to get and send the current value of my three fields to a service and calculate the value for my last field in there. The problem was that it generated a lot of traffic and slowed down my application. If i tried to write my own number into the last field, the input got instantly overwrote by the value which the service returned. I want the user to be able to overwrite the autofilled field and autoclear the other fields

My approach:

The hook in my third formly field which checks if two fields are filled:

```ts
hooks: {
    doCheck: (field: FormlyFieldConfig) => {
        let fields = field.form.getRawValue();

        if ( 
            fields.fieldOne.value !== null && 
            fields.fieldTwo.value !== null &&
            fields.fieldThree.value  !== calculateFieldsService.calculateFieldThree(
                fields.fieldOne,
                fields.fieldTwo
            )
        ) {
            fields.fieldThree.value = calculateFieldsService.calculateFieldThree(
                fields.fieldOne,
                fields.fieldTwo
            )   
            field.form.setValue({...fields, ...fields} );
        }
    }
}
```

The service which should calculate my field value if two fields are filled:

```ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CalculateFieldsService { 

  calculateFieldThree(fieldOne, fieldTwo): number {
    if (fieldOne.value >= 0 && fieldTwo.value >= 0) {
      let fieldValue = 100 - (fieldOne.value + fieldTwo.value);    
      return fieldValue < 0 ? 0 : fieldValue;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO `doCheck` is not the right way, with `formly` there are two ways that to autofill a field:

- Use `expressionProperties`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-bootstrap-4ryvgk

```html
expressionProperties: {
  'model.c': (m) => {
    return m.a && m.b ? (m.a + m.b) : null;
  }
}
```

- subscribe to `form.valueChanges`